# This function has a fixed point, $F^4(x)=x$. Why?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, cross-product, fixed-points

[image: unit sphere]

Consider two points on the unit sphere, $C_1$ and $C_2$. Let these points be close enough such that circles of radius $r$ drawn around each point intersect at two points, $N_1$ and $N_2$. The vectors that point to $N_1$ and $N_2$ can be found by the following formula:

$$
f(C_1, C_2) = k\frac{\vec{C_1}+\vec{C_2}}{|\vec{C_1}+\vec{C_2}|} \pm \sqrt{1-k^2}\frac{\vec{C_1}\times\vec{C_2}}{|\vec{C_1}\times\vec{C_2}|}
$$

Where $k = \cos(\theta)/\cos(\alpha/2)$,  $\theta$ is the half angle of the circle from the origin and $\alpha$ the angle between the vectors pointing to $C_1$ and $C_2$.

If one interprets the $\pm$ as producing two separate vectors, then $f(\vec{C_1},\vec{C_2}) = (\vec{N_1},\vec{N_2})$. Furthermore, the function is almost it's own inverse, that is: $f(\vec{N_1},\vec{N_2}) = (\vec{C_2},\vec{C_1})$. I say almost since the order of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is reversed. It takes four applications of $f$ to return to the original configuration:

$$
f^{(4)}(\vec{C_1},\vec{C_2}) = (\vec{C_1},\vec{C_2})
$$

> #### Question:
>
> Why $f^{(4)}(x) = x$? I was surprised that I couldn't simply make this function $f^{(2)}(x) = x$.  Is there a good reason for this on $\mathbb{R}^3$? Is this sort of behavior categorizable? Perhaps as a mini-lecture on group theory? An accepted answer would explain if $f^{(2)}(x) = x$ is possible in this context, and if not explain why.

Comment: Loosely speaking, it seems that $f$ needs to **commute** with rotations, which encourages it to **be** a rotation itself, and not a reflection. You might be able to formalize that idea as a rigorous answer by focusing on special cases where the C axis and the N axis have the same length, so that there is a *bona fide* 90-degree rotation interchanging them.